# Prevent user from putting Tag in both Favorite and Ignored Tags

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching, ignored-tags

I accidentally ended up with php in both my favourite and ignored tags.

This lead to some [weird behaviour](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306409/why-are-these-questions-i-dont-have-on-my-ignored-list-of-tags-greyed-out?noredirect=1#comment249136_306409) with highlighting and greying out of questions.

Can a user be prevented from adding a tag to ignored if it is already in Favourites?